# Showing javascript backtraces in Capybara + Poltergeist

Tags: javascript, ruby, capybara, poltergeist

I'm working on a Ruby application that is using Capybara and Poltergeist to do some web-related stuff.

Capybara is being initialized the following way:

```
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
    Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, :js_errors => true, :debug => true)
end
default_driver = :poltergeist
Capybara.default_driver = default_driver
Capybara.javascript_driver = default_driver
Capybara.current_driver = default_driver
Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 30
```

I know the javascript that is being ran is failing at some point, probably because of a typo (but it could be because of some other reason), but I don't see any *backtraces* when I run the application (`bundle exec rake myapp:console`). I do see the debug output, which is pretty much useless.

I also see some of my `console.log`calls (I'm guessing that the one's I don't see fail in some way or Ruby just doesn't know how to print those).

My question is: how can I see some useful output that would help me debug my JS code?

PS: Please note that the entire application is running inside Docker, so keep that in mind if you're going to recommend me switching from Poltergeist.

Answer (score 1):

Before running the relevant page code, do

```
page.driver.enable_logging
```

As mentioned [here](https://github.com/thoughtbot/capybara-webkit/issues/684#issuecomment-63080829) (although in relation to webkit driver), it should show the console errors as well.

Comment: I don't have any tests. I'm trying to debug some methods in my application, so I'm not really sure all that `describe ....` applies here. Or does it?

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted your question. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Your update is for `-webkit`. I'm using `poltergeist`. So I'm (expectedly) getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'enable_logging' for #<Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver:0x00564fed71de08>`

Comment: It is not 'expectedly'. Capybara drivers share a good deal of API so it was worth trying.

Comment: Have you looked here https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/pull/230, at `:phantomjs_logger` option?

Comment: Yes, this is how it currently works by default (printing to `STDOUT`). That's how I see some of my `console.log` calls.

Comment: There is a link on the previous page to an opposite issue. Might be worth it to check whether all the relevant callbacks are defined and inject the missing ones if any: https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist/issues/94#issuecomment-11535921